# How do you delete an example?

Tags: support, documentation

Today I saw a big banner telling me all about the new Documentation feature.

So I had a go at writing a simple example. Suffice it to say, everybody hates it. I've had a huge bunch of comments telling me how awful my example is.

So how do I delete my example? I can't find a delete button *anywhere!*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, a little bit of clarification: it isn't *your* example. It's just an example you created. Ownership in Documentation is a bit different from Q&A — hence why you earn reputation for upvotes on a topic you edit, even if you weren't the person who originally created it.

That put aside, you should be able to do one of two things:

- Click [on the little red trash can that appears *after* you start editing an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Us772.png);
- Or you can mark the example as unnecessary and wait for your peers to review it.

Comment: I see. Clearly it's extremely dangerous to touch stuff you don't understand. I will be more careful to avoid new functionality in future.

Comment: Your screenshot makes it very unclear *where on the screen* this button is supposed to appear. I eventually managed to find it. But now I can't tell if the example is gone; every time I visit the topic, it drops me straight back into edit mode, and I can't get out of it...

Comment: Edited the screenshot.

Comment: @JNat Is there a way to roll back my contribution on example or on topic level? I know that I can manually delete it but it cannot get through the review.